# Вытащить текст из выражения

Tags: php

Пишу свой шаблонизатор, и запуталась на моменте -

```
{%if a<5 %}
```

как отсюда мне вытащить именно а<5 и само выражение, чтобы в дальнейшем заменить на php код
перепробовала

```
  preg_match('{%if.*%}',$this->currentFile,$matches);
```

не достается

Comment: `'{%if(.*)%}'` не?

Comment: `preg_match('{%if.*%}',$this->currentFile,$matches);
        echo $matches[0];`  - ничего не выводит @ArchDemon

Comment: а нет, выводит, а как мне оттуда достать то, что между?

Comment: Я же вам написал. Сделайте `var_dump($matches)` и увидите

Comment: Вам будет проще взять готовый шаблонизатор, тот же твиг. смарти и т.д., да посмотреть как устроено и взять нужные компоненты за основу. То что вы пишите сейчас никуда не годится.